# Is there a way to pass an argument from a command inside main bot.py file to a cog discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I would like to pass an argument (channel id) from this command:

```
@bot.command()
async def countingon(ctx):
    if (ctx.message.author.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel).manage_messages):
        bot.load_extension('cogs.counting')
        await ctx.send('Counting is on')
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't do that!")
```

To a cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import command

a = 1
target : discord.Member
class counting(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot  

    

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == ({argument here}):
    ...
```

I have no clue on how to do that, so I'm asking here

Answer (score 1):

Add the channel ID as argument to the cog constructor:

```py
class counting(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot, channel_id):
        self.bot = bot
        self.channel_id = channel_id
```

Then check in `on_message` using:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.channel.id == self.channel_id:
        ...
```

To pass the channel ID to the cog, use [`bot.add_cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_cog) instead of `load_extension`:

```py
from cogs import counting

@bot.command()
async def countingon(ctx):
    if ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.channel).manage_messages:
        # you probably also need to check if the cog is already loaded here
        bot.add_cog(counting(bot, ctx.channel.id))
        await ctx.send("Counting is on")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't do that!")
```

Comment: Did not work, shows no error in console tho

Comment: @NimVrod Must be something on your end, since this works fine for me. Try debugging the command to see where it goes wrong.