# I need to transport the "canalticket" variable as a parameter to the cogs setup. But I have no idea how to do that. (Discord.py 2.0)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
import discord
import time

class ticket(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def teste(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("ola", view=PersistentView())

class PersistentView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Teste1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="", custom_id='persistent_view:ptbr')
    async def button1_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        overwrite = {
            interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        }
        categ = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, name=" ┇ Tickets")
        canalticket = await categ.create_text_channel(name=f"・{interaction.user.display_name}", overwrites=overwrite)
        view = PersistentViewPT(canalticket)
        await interaction.response.send_message(content = "Channel created!", view = view)

class PersistentViewPT(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, canalticket):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.canalticket = canalticket
    @discord.ui.button(label="Teste2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id='persistent_view:fechar')
    async def button1_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content = "Funcionou!")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(ticket(bot))
    bot.add_view(PersistentView())
```

NOTE: I need to transport it there, because I want to make a PersistentView, but I don't want to use a database to store these variables.

[This is what I need to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Koj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to pass an argument from a command inside main bot.py file to a cog discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525003/is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-argument-from-a-command-inside-main-bot-py-file-to-a-c)

Comment: I tested this but it didn't work, I can't import the cogs.